# Initial Elastic Load Balancer connections hang

Tags: amazon-web-services, load-balancing, docker

I have an elastic load balancer running in front of a Go-based docker service that is on two machines.  Every time I restart the Go service, the initial connections from some clients take minutes before failing and retrying, which eventually works.  It's not the health check (which adds up to ~1 minute), and what is bizarre is that it seems to be either by machine or by session.

At this point my idle timeout is set to 1 second.

So, for example, after the health checks are good:

- I will hard refresh a page in chrome and it will load right away
- I will try to curl the page from the same computer and it will hang (and I will not see the access in the server logs)
- I will try to curl the individual service and it works instantly
- I will try to connect from a mobile client and it times out
- I will curl from another computer and it works

Am I missing something here?  I do not have sticky sessions enabled, and it seems to me like each of these should be working instantly.  Is there some sort of client-based limit on ELB connections?

Comment: Do an nslookup on the ELB hostname (elb-name-nnnn.re-gio-n.elb.amazonaws.com, not an alias).  There should be multiple IP addresses returned (at least 2, sometimes more).  If you access the service using each of these IP addresses directly, one at a time, is there a pattern?  How long do you let curl sit there when it is hung? *Something* should eventually happen, and that "something" could be informative, particularly if it occurs on a "round number" time interval, like 60 or 300 seconds.

Comment: It does seem like one of the IP addresses isn't accepting connections - didn't realize there were two.  I'm guessing I just need to kill the load balancer somehow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this particular case the problem was that the elastic load balancer was set to run in multiple subnets, and some of the subnets were not publicly accessible, and thus some requests were being routed to a bad IP.

The confusion came because we misunderstood what the subnet setting on the ELB meant.

So check your subnets!